# Can I define a variable for a list of values in SqlPlus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a script (for Oracle) with a number of sql statements that all target the same list of values, for example

```
select * from s1.t1 where f1 in ('val1', 'val2')
select * from s2.t2 where f2 in ('val1', 'val2')
-- etc.
```

Instead of pasting this list of values in at each place in the script, I would like to define a variable to hold that list, and then use it in the correct place, something like:

```
define var1 = "('val1','val2')"
select * from s1.t1 where f1 in &&var1
select * From s2.t2 where f2 in &&var1
```

When I attempt it the way it's written above, I get the error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended", and the verified statement in the log looks like:

```
select * from s1.t1 where f1 in '('val1','val2')'
```

So I can see that the variable substitution is putting single quotes around my entire variable value, which is sort of reasonable but not what I want. Is there a way to get done what I want here?

Comment: Is that exactly what you run? You're missing semicolons at the end of the statements - which would throw that error. The substitution look OK though - I don't see how you're getting the final code you showed, with the extra single quotes, from the earlier statements.

Comment: ... unless you're really doing `select * From s2.t2 where f2 in '&&var1';` with quotes around the substitution variables; but you haven't shown that if so.

Comment: You called the shot - had single quotes around the &&var and didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'verified statement' ends up as:

```
select * from s1.t1 where f1 in '('val1','val2')'
```

which means that, if you've defined the substitution variable as you said, your query is actually then using it as:

```
select * from s1.t1 where f1 in '&&var1';

old:select * from s1.t1 where f1 in '&&var1'
new:select * from s1.t1 where f1 in '('val1','val2')'

SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Enclosing the variable in single quotes is necessary when the value is an unquoted string, which is usually the case with `new_value` and by default with `define` or `accept` or when prompted for the variable value. But here your variable value already has all the quotes you need, so it should just be as you actually showed it in your question, without the quotes:

```
select * from s1.t1 where f1 in &&var1;

old:select * from s1.t1 where f1 in &&var1
new:select * from s1.t1 where f1 in ('val1','val2')
```

which is now valid.

Answer (score 0):

Works OK for me; example based on Scott's EMP table:

```
SQL> define vjob = "('CLERK', 'MANAGER')"
SQL> select count(*) from emp where job in &vjob;
old   1: select count(*) from emp where job in &vjob
new   1: select count(*) from emp where job in ('CLERK', 'MANAGER')

  COUNT(*)
----------
         7
```